# How to use words in c language arrays?

Tags: c

I'm learning C language and using VBCC as compiler with C99 standard. Trying to figure out how to print multi character elements from array, but `printf` warn me the type of argument is not matching. It's "just" a warning but i want to understand what i'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    const char* s[] = {"aa","hey","2","1","111","\0"}; 
        int a = 0;
        do {
            printf("%p\n",&s[a]);
            a = a + 1;
        } while (s[a] != '\0');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `printf` format strings? You do know that `%p` is for printing a pointer, right? Not for printing the string that `&s[a]` points to, or for printing a character. Also note that `'\0'` and `"\0"` are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i thought '\0' and "\0" are same.

Comment: Good for you to not ignore warnings.

Comment: `'\0'` is the character whose value is 0. `"\0"` is a pointer to a string that consists of just the character 0.

Comment: I guess i got down votes for a question which answered many times ? Should i delete my question ?

Comment: @lurker — `”\0”` is a pointer to two consecutive null bytes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yep, right! Thanks for clarifying. I was referring to the string without considering the terminating null.

Answer (score 4):

> It's "just" a warning

Well, yes, the compiler may only emit a warning, but it doesn't mean that what you are doing is not an error. Indeed, most of the time it is. As a novice C programmer, you should basically always treat warnings as errors.

What you're doing here:

```
const char* s[] = {"aa","hey","2","1","111","\0"};
```

Is declaring an array of `char*` (`char` pointers), and assigning to each of the pointers in the array the address of a valid string (provided in the initializer `{...}`).

This is the same as doing:

```
const char *s[6];
s[0] = "aa";
s[1] = "hey";
// ... and so on
```

*Each of the strings* will be automatically NUL-terminated with the `\0` terminator, which is implicit when using the syntax `"string literal"`. The last string that you are adding is unnecessary and empty, and it also contains two terminators, the one you explicitly add and the one implicitly added by default.

Now, to the errors. What you are doing here:

```
printf("%p\n", &s[a]);
```

Is incorrect. If you want to print the `a-th` string, you already have a pointer to it in `s[a]`, so you don't need to take the address (`&`) again. Another error is using the `%p` format specifier (I assume you changed it because the compiler told you so), which is not for strings, but for generic pointers (in this case is correct since `&s[a]` is actually a pointer, but remember that you want to print a string). In the end the above line compiles fine, but it's not what you want. The correct syntax is:

```
printf("%s\n", s[a]);
```

The real error in your code is here:

```
while (s[a] != '\0');
```

Here, you are comparing a string with a `char` literal (namely the terminator). You cannot do this, since the two types are different. If you want to terminate your array with a correct value that can then be compared, you can use `NULL`, since it's an array of pointers (`char*`).

Another logical error is that you are using a `do {...} while` cycle, and checking if you reached the end only *after* printing. In the specific case of your program (with an array of 6 strings) nothing bad happens, but if your array is empty (e.g. `char *s[] = {NULL};`) you will try to print the first element anyway, which is an error.

Here's the code with the corrections applied:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    const char* s[] = {"aa", "hey", "2", "1", "111", NULL}; 

    int a = 0;
    while (s[a] != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", s[a]);
        a = a + 1;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Marco thanks the nice explanation, things are more clear now !

Comment: @DanielDechevIvanov if my answer helped you solve the problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark icon on the top-left corner, that way your question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2):

All strings in C end with zero. You have a table of pointers here and as a marker you should use NULL. 
https://godbolt.org/z/KJCdsi

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    const char* s[] = {"aa","hey","2","1","111", NULL}; 
        int a = 0;
        do {
            printf("s[%d] = %s\n", a, s[a]);
            a = a + 1;
        } while (s[a]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "%s" format specifier for printing strings, and remove the `&` reference operator.

```
printf("%s\n",s[a]);
```

Comment: Thx, that solved the warning. Actually i'm still not clearly understand how pointers works, but working on it :)